# Selenium Select Dropdown list

Tags: python, selenium

could you help me, I'm trying to select a item in a dropdownlist.
What is the better way to do this?

```
<div class="field-unit__field">
  <select name="PLAYERS[players_id]" id="PLAYERS_players_id"><option value="" label=" "></option>
<option value="1">CRISTIANO RONALDO</option>
<option value="3">NEYMAR</option>
<option value="2">MESSI</option>
<option value="4">MODRIC</option></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("PLAYERS_players_id"))
--Use one of the following methods to select the options
select.select_by_index(0)
select.select_by_visible_text("")
select.select_by_value("")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "find_element_by_xpath" like

```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='element_name']/option[text()='option_text']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium import webdriver
...
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path) #Driver path

sel = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("PLAYERS_players_id"))
sel.select_by_index(1) # To select element by indedx
sel.select_by_visible_text("1") # To select By visible text
```

Answer (score 0):

This HTML is built using Select and Options tags. Selenium has inbuilt Class `Select` to handle drop down built using  select and options tag.

**Code :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('PLAYERS_players_id'))
#select.select_by_index(index)
select.select_by_visible_text("MESSI")
#select.select_by_value(value)
```

Reference [official link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms)